# Сводная таблица excel в R Studio

Tags: r, datatable, rstudio

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно подготовить файл формата excel со сводной таблицей для загрузки его в R Studio? Я попыталась просто файл импортировать, но названия столбцов в числовом формате (это коды товарной номенклатуры), и поэтому не читаются, а ненужные ячейки, которые сохранились из excel файла ("название строк", "название столбцов"), смещают значения в середине поля (стоимость экспорта).

Заранее огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: А так ли надо именно сводную таблицу закачивать? Может быть легче закачать исходные данные для сводной таблицы, а саму таблицу уже в R построить?

Comment: Как раз зарелизили недавно. https://blog.rstudio.org/2017/04/19/readxl-1-0-0/

Answer (score 1):

Для иллюстрации. 
Имеем таблицу в формате MS Excel:

[image: Структура таблицы]

на основе которой получаем сводную таблицу:

[image: Сводная таблица]

Условие: наименования столбцов - представлены в виде чисел.

Отвечая на конкретный вопрос:

> как правильно подготовить файл формата excel со сводной таблицей для загрузки его в R Studio?

следует выполнить "Сохранить / Сохранить как" указать значение "Тип файла" CSV(разделитель - запятые)(*.csv).
В результате будет следующий вид содержимого файла:
[image: csv-file]

который можно загрузить следующей командой:

```
# загружаем данные из файла csv 
xls.c.fl <- "D://-DtFls//so 655842.csv"
xls.c.tbl <- read.csv(xls.c.fl, header = TRUE, skip = 1, sep = ";")
```

но в результате получим имена столбцов вида X....
[image: R data frame csv]

Поэтому самый оптимальный вариант предложил Artem Klevtsov. Использовать `readxl`.

```
#загружаем данные непосредственно из сводной таблицы Excel  
library(readxl)
xls.fl <- "D://-DtFls//so 655842.xlsx"
xls.a.tbl <- read_excel(xls.fl, sheet = 1, col_names = TRUE, skip = 3)
```

В итоге получаем (все заголовки, представленные числами, отображаются корректно):

[image: R used readxl]

Answer (score 0):

При создании файла эксель нужно сохранить его в формате .csv, соответственно, задать разделители(по канону - запятая), к тому же прописать в R при импорте в команде значение разделителя и headers = TRUE, если импорт в ручную, то, соответственно, выбрать из списка нужный разделитель или поставить галочку напротив заголовков

Comment: Поправте орфографию и пунктуацию.